# How do I work backwards in R or Python to get a file saved as .cat to open?

Tags: cat

I'm trying to open a dictionary file that is in ".cat" format.  However, I can't get it to open and I've tried multiple ways.  Help!

I have Mac and Windows software to use.

Comment: If you post what you tried, someone might be able to help fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.